# Offline code signature verification scheme

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, rsa

Assume that I want to sign digitally updates for an offline appliance (lets say a limited linux VM). To begin with, such mechanism is not in place and the very limited OS doesn't have any CA certificates. Secondly, any update can be uploaded only with removable media, so no Internet connection.

This scenario creates an already unsafe state, that I want to upgrade to a safer state. In this case I want to verify and authenticate my code to the appliance. We can assume that a certificate is not necessary (or maybe not?), since to begin with there is no a CA established (and not accessible in any method), and we proceed with just a classic RSA pair key signing process.

The first problem I see is the first update that will provide the public key to the appliance. Since we start from an unsafe state, I suppose we cannot resolve this. We have to accept that the first update might be malicious. But from that point on, each update could be verified by the public key.

The main problem is how to maintain such an approach. If for some reason the appliance looses its public key, is there a way to provide the public key with some confidence that the process is safe even if there is a cost in user experiece? For example if I provide the public key in an https site with its hash, and perhaps with a login process, could this resolve this edge case, as long as I trust the https connection? In this case I still used removable media, I just download the update (or the public key) from an other system and require some manual work from the user.

Is there a better approach that I might want dig into, to provide a better scheme with these conditions

Comment: Is it possible to make manual initial appliance provisioning? You could configure public key to trust.

Comment: This scenario cannot work if you have to send the update, in case the appliance is already deployed. But ofc we can do it in case of the new images.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you _can't_ nuke and rebuild into a more secure configuration? And yes, you're correct about not being able to verify the first update; there's a reason most computers today come _preinstalled_ with a trust store. You can't turn an untrusted channel into a trusted one from absolutely nothing.

Comment: Basically, the issue is that if you already have deployed appliances you cannot go back. In a sense, this is an accepted risk (or perhaps an unavoidable one) that I have to live with. But even if I have accept this risk, I still have the issue of maintenance.

Comment: Please describe how your update process works currently: where the update is stored, how users acquire the update, how do they install it. Also clarify what do you mean by “If for some reason the appliance looses its public key”. If code signature validation is going to be a part of the update process then “lost” public key is equivalent to damaged update mechanism. What if I loose `/bin/*`? I salvage data and reinstall the OS.

Comment: Update process: The user will download the update from a site, put it in removable media, and install it to the offline appliance. I want the appliance to validate the update. Moving to the lost public key, I simply want to cover the scenario that the key is lost. We can simply describe this as "Reasons why the client does not have a valid public key and what to do about it". Maybe he lost the initial update that installs the key and attempts to install the next update, or maybe I changed the public key (expired or something) with a signed update, and someone missed it.

Comment: You cannot trust a https connection any more than a http connection, if you have no roots of trust available.